# How to handle JWT expiration in Spring security and JwtBuilder (should I use cookie max age)

Tags: spring, http, authentication, cookies, jwt

Is the expiration field of JWT token semantic, or should it be used to check token validity instead of simply setting JWT containing cookie's max age to correspond the expiration time? Latter options seems simpler, as no additional validation logic is needed, Spring will detect the expired cookie automatically.

Is this approved in the case of JWT token?

Answer (score 0):

It is not appropriate to use the cookie max age. JWT is a self-contained format and is independent of the storage mode. In a browser can be stored by any means available: cookie, localStorage, IndexedDB, etc. In a server or standalone system it could be stored id any way. It is not convenient to attach the token expiration to the storage mode because you can not control it.

Let see [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#page-9)

> The "exp" (expiration time) claim identifies the expiration time on or after which the JWT MUST NOT be accepted for processing.  The processing of the "exp" claim requires that the current date/time MUST be before the expiration date/time listed in the "exp" claim.

So **it is mandatory to check the expiration time** (if field is set)